# How to get specific element from array of type any in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Tom Harrys",
        "email" : "tommyHarrys@abc.com",
        "password" : "tomharry123"
    },
    
    {
        "name" : "Sam Billing",
        "email" : "samybilling@abc.com",
        "password" : "sambillings789"
    },
    
    {
        "name" : "Adam Gosh",
        "email" : "adagoshy@abc.com",
        "password" : "adamghosy989"
    }
]
```

UTIL file:

```
class Utils {
  static func loadData(filename : String) -> [Any] {
    let filePath = Bundle(for: self).path(forResource: filename, ofType: "json") ?? "default"
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    do {
      let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
       let exampleArray =  json as! [Any]
       if exampleArray.isEmpty {
         XCTFail("Source file \(filename) is empty.")
      }
       return exampleArray
    }
    catch {
       XCTFail("Error: \(error)")

       XCTFail("File \(filename) not found.")
       return []
    }
  }
}
```

Test file:

```
func loginAccount() {
  let dataSource = Utils.loadData(filename: "example")
  dataSource.contains(where: { ($0.name == "Sam Billing"})         
}
```

In this code dataSource got 3 value same as Json file.
Now I want to fill the sign up form with specific value

(   "name" : "Sam Billing",
"email" : "samybilling@abc.com",
"password" : "sambillings789"
)

from the array.

Comment: Do not have an array of type Any. Do not use JSONSerialization. Use Decodable.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `JSONSerializer` in Swift.  A better option is a `JSONDecoder`. `JSONDecoder` will allow you to establish and preserve the type information for the data you've decoded. Here is an Playground example of how you would use `JSONDecoder` to handle this data set, then one technique extract Sam's record from the array of users.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let JSONContent = """
[
    {
        "name" : "Tom Harrys",
        "email" : "tommyHarrys@abc.com",
        "password" : "tomharry123"
    },

    {
        "name" : "Sam Billing",
        "email" : "samybilling@abc.com",
        "password" : "sambillings789"
    },

    {
        "name" : "Adam Gosh",
        "email" : "adagoshy@abc.com",
        "password" : "adamghosy989"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct UserRecord : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let email: String
    let password: String // Don't pass passwords in plain text around in JSON
}

class Utils {
    static func loadData() -> [UserRecord] {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let data = JSONContent
            let json = try decoder.decode([UserRecord].self, from: data)
            return json
        }
        catch let error {
            print("The json could not be decoded \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }

}


let users = Utils.loadData()
if let sam = users.first(where: { user in user.email.caseInsensitiveCompare("samybilling@abc.com") == .orderedSame }) {
    debugPrint(sam)
} else {
    print("Sam was missing")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try it. And can you please suggest that how can I do iteration over the data set when I want to fill the data into my sign up form in series. let say sign up for 10 accounts all one after the other.